# error with file get content and curl

Tags: php, curl

i have a doc file on my remote host and i want to open it from another host with curl . my code on file host is

```
if(strlen($type) == 0){
        $type = 'application/octetstream';
    }
    header("Content-type: $type");  
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
echo file_get_contents("target of my file");
```

i get type from my database . for this file , type is "application/msword" .
my code in another server that we want use curl to echo that file is :

```
$ch = curl_init("address of host"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "post data to find that file");    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$res = curl_exec($ch);    
curl_close($ch);
echo  $res;
```

but when i execute i see a page with ambigiuse words and digit like "... „‚Úh^h^h^”þ”þ‚Úh^h^h^_h^h^h^h^ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ... "!

Comment: Looks like you're simply not setting the response headers on your *curl* end before `echo`-ing the data, specifically, `Content-type`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file_get_contents` with URL's if your server is setup to allow this. Removing the need for curl at all.

Comment: how  setup my server to allow use file_get_content with url ?

Comment: excuse me but i cant undrestand meaning of "Removing the need for curl at all"

Comment: i dont use url with file get content . i use it to open a file located on localhost then target like this "/datastorage/storage/c4356.doc"